# Mikro-orm error TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework, mikro-orm

When I execute any command in mikro-orm cli, the following error appears:

`TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\UsersDesktopintegration-list-restrictive-mikro-orm.config.ts`

Command run: `npx mikro-orm migration:create -i`

Comment: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/3442

Answer (score 2):

I had this error in ESM project, and solved it with running `npx mikro-orm-esm migration:create` instead of `npx mikro-orm migration:create`